# what maven dependency do I need to load an OSGi FrameworkFactory

Tags: java, maven, osgi, integration

I want to use one of the examples [to launch a FrameworkFactory](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.osgi.framework.launch.FrameworkFactory). Either my compiler refuses to compile ...

```
 Map<String,String> props=new HashMap<String,String>();
 props.put("org.osgi.framework.storage","target/osgi-store");
 props.put("org.osgi.framework.storage.clean","onFirstInit");
 FrameworkFactory factory=ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class);
 // Type mismatch: cannot convert from ServiceLoader<FrameworkFactory> to FrameworkFactory
```

or the vm fails load a factory ...

```
ServiceLoader<FrameworkFactory> loader = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class);
Iterator<FrameworkFactory> iter = loader.iterator();
FrameworkFactory ff = iter.next(); // there is no "next"
```

This is my pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>prices.otemba.org</groupId>
<artifactId>PricesFromOtemba</artifactId>

<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\javac.exe</executable>
                </configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime</artifactId>
        <version>0.16.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

If you have a suggestion concerning my pom in general then please feel free to advice.

Comment: Solved the issue with ...   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>runtime</artifactId>
   <version>3.10.0-v20140318-2214</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: if you solved it, either answer your own question so this question wil be closed. Or delete it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSGi got FrameworkFactory could not be instantiated Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42760795/osgi-got-frameworkfactory-could-not-be-instantiated-error)

Answer (score 1):

So the following entry:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Adds the OSGi 4.3 API to your project (note that 4.3.1 or higher is needed for generics to work). This is providing you with the `FrameworkFactory` interface, but no implementation for the service loader to find. To get an implementation you need to have an OSGi R4.3 (or higher) framework on your class path at runtime.

For example to add the Apache Felix framework R6 implementation (which is backward compatible with the R4.3 API) you would add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1</version>
    <!-- You aren't compiling against Felix, just using it at runtime -->
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I would also suggest removing the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The reason you should remove this is that it is a much older version of the OSGi API jar. It doesn't contain the FrameworkFactory interface (it predates it) and it will clash with the OSGi 4.3 API that is also on your compilation path.

Answer (score 0):

So my question is about [java.util.ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html) states: "It searches for service providers on your application's class path". I built the examples and have strong doubts about that statement. The examples need to be assembled in a .jar with a subdirectory in the META-INF, having the full qualified name of the service.

In this case that would be the full qualified name of the class that implements org.osgi.framework.launch.FrameworkFactory.

So I checked my M2 repository if the bundle org.osgi.core has such an entry. The answer is no.

Conclusion: The examples that I used are not suitable for bundles that were not prepared for java.util.ServiceLoader